# ideas about the algorithm: initial seeds growing with different rate of growth to fill the 2D space

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I'm looking for the algorithm to apply in c++ program to generate a 2D plane filled with costume shapes. These costume shapes are different in size and orientation. 
The aim is to use initial seeds that each one can have different growth rate (in different direction).
They continue growing until they touch each other edge and fill the space in between.

So we want to apply the following properties to each seed at start:
- Seed grow rate (in different directions like up,right,down,left)
- Seed growing shape

Note: I already used Voronoi Diagram, Apollonius Diagram.

Every idea and help is most appreciated.

Comment: How much precision do you need?  Would a pixel-based algorithm be sufficient?

Comment: yep, That would be enough for now.